# DOMPDF doesn't work with external css file

Tags: css, zend-framework, dompdf

I'm using Zend Framework and DOMPDF library. When I test it with inline css everything works perfectly. But when I tried to move css code to the external file rules are not applied to the html page.

Here is my code.

1. Code of controller's action, which generate pdf

require_once("DomPdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

```
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    $html = $this->view->render('index/dom.phtml');

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();

    $pdfContent =   $dompdf->output();

    file_put_contents('sample.pdf', $pdfContent);

    die("test");
```

2.Code of corresponding view (index/dom.phtml)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="/themes/css/pdf.css" rel="stylesheet"   media="screen"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div>Tamara testing</div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

3.And my css file:

```
div {color: red;}
```

How to make it works?

UPDATE:

To make it works I changed the following things:

1.In controller's action add base path for external files

```
$dompdf->set_base_path(APPLICATION_PATH."/../public/themes/css/");
```

2.In view change href attribute of the link tag. Make it relative to the base path set in step 1.

```
<link type="text/css" href="pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: In case someone finds this on a search engine (just like I did), please note there's another option called `DOMPDF::set_protocol()`, see my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has in fact nothing to do with Zend Framework, but you need to supply DomPDF the right path to load the "external" files from.

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->setBasePath(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/path/to/css/'));
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
```

See also the [manual](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#set_base_path) of DomPDF for this feature.

Answer (score 6):

@Jurian Sluiman is on the right track, though his answer did not help me, unfortunately.

I had to spend some time in order to find the solution that worked for me, which was using `DOMPDF::set_protocol()`:

```
$dompdf->set_protocol(WWW_ROOT);
$dompdf->set_base_path('/');
```

`WWW_ROOT` here is a [CakePHP constant](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#WWW_ROOT) pointing to the webroot folder of my application. *Note that it has a trailing slash.*

The best part is that this seems like improper usage of `set_protocol()`. But I'm fine with that as long as it makes the CSS work.

- https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/search?q=set_protocol
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/dompdf/uBWdQbug_dM
- http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility

Hope this saves someone else few hours of time.

Comment: Thanks @aexl, this saved me a lot of time

Comment: Thanks, but what worked for me was ```$options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);  $options->setChroot(array_merge($options->getChroot(), [WWW_ROOT]));```. Actually, after setting the ```Chroot``` I didn't even have to ```$dompdf->setBasePath(WWW_ROOT);``` which was as expected after reading the docs. I think it wouldn't work without CHROOT for security. Check the [docs](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#security-restrictions-for-local-files).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jurian Sluiman's answer, I had to allow Dompdf to access the base path in order for CSS styling and images to work:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf(['chroot' => __DIR__]);
$dompdf->setBasePath(__DIR__ . '/path/to/assets/'));
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
```