# dompdf styles not working in server

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

I use dompdf library with codeigniter to generate report as html. In this case pdf is generate in local machine. But when i upload same code to the server machine styles is not working. But i check the related html page. It is showing with styles.

This is my library file.

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

class pdf extends DOMPDF
{

    private $html = '';

    protected function ci()
    {
        return get_instance();
    }

    public function load_view($view, $data = array())
    {
        $this->html .= $this->ci()->load->view($view, $data, TRUE);
    }

    public function render($file)
    {
        // echo $this->html; die;
        $this->load_html($this->html);
        parent::render();
        $this->stream($file);
    }
}
```

I try check html after remove comment of `echo $this->html; die;`

This is my action

```
public function download()
{
    $this->load->library('pdf');

    $this->pdf->load_view('pdf/header');
    $this->pdf->load_view('pdf/test');
    $this->pdf->load_view('pdf/footer');

    $this->pdf->render('ttt.pdf');
}
```

And views

pdf/header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dddd</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="<?php print base_url(); ?>css/pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="header">
                <a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>">
                    <h2>ddddd</h2>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
```

pdf/test

```
<h3>SECTION 17 APPLICATION</h3>
<h4>1) Particulars of Investors</h4>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>      
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>US $ Min</th>
            <th>%</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a) Name :- </td>
            <td>tttttt</td>
            <td>dfsdfsdf</td>            
        </tr>      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

pdf/footer

```
        </div>
        <footer>
            &copy; <?php print date('Y'); ?> ddddd. All Rights Reserved
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of dompdf? Does `base_url()` return something like `http://example.com...`. If so you may need to set DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE to true.

Answer (score 1):

DomPDF does not load external CSS by default see: [DOMPDF doesn't work with external css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185531/dompdf-doesnt-work-with-external-css-file)

You can also look into the manual: [DOM pdf manual](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#set_base_path)