# Bootstrap.min.css file is not calling in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

i designed the invoice using bootstrap css, i used tcpdf to design invoice. I called bootstrap css file but its not working, Kindly help me.. My coding is

```
$baseurl = "http://localhost/erp";
$html = '<style>'.file_get_contents($baseurl.'css/bootstrap.min.css').'</style>';
$html = '<style>'.file_get_contents($baseurl.'css/style.css').'</style>';
```

Comment: What does _its not working_? Please add some detail

Comment: @il_raffa the values are working fine, i wanna design my invoice page by using css file so i called bootstrap css file.. the thing is bootstrap css file is not working

Comment: @il_raffa i called a css file like $html = '<style>'.file_get_contents($baseurl.'css/bootstrap.min.css').'</style>'; but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - `Bootstrap` use `js` scripts for working; As You understand, scripts could not be working in `tcpdf` file;
More than that - `tcpdf` not allowed all CSS attributes; I can't find supported css list in [official documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html), but [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11436355/3335966);

Comment: thank you for your information. Now I used **dompdf**. It supported CSS files. But here also i faced the same problem

Comment: @sathish I dnt work with `dompdf`, and if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185531/dompdf-doesnt-work-with-external-css-file/17186282#17186282) not help You, then, in my opinion, problem in bootstrap =) Try copy needful class code from `bootstrap.css` to Your `php` code.