# Laravel domPDF cant load external css files

Tags: php, css, laravel, pdf, pdf-generation

I am using domPDF for generating PDF's after a user submit a button. I noticed that if I use

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('health/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">`

it will not generate PDF and it is always loading forever. I tried to use `file_get_contents` but seems it is not also working. Can someone tell me what should I do about this? If you know.

Controller

```
        $css = 'health/css/bootstrap.min.css';
        $data_type = pathinfo($css, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $css_data = file_get_contents($css);

        //I can get the image by using this code
        $path = 'health/img/logo.png';
        $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = file_get_contents($path);
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

        //for testing view
        return view('emails.form',compact('base64','css_data'));
```

Blade

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{$css_data}}">
 <img src="{{$base64}}" class="img img-fluid img-center">
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

DomPDF requires using the absolute local path to the CSS file in your link element's href attribute, rather than the external URL to the file.

You'd want to use something similar to the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path('health/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

This is the same for any external resource you wish to use (CSS, Image, etc.)

You can find more information about this [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#referencing-resources-like-images) from their GitHub wiki.

If you are using DomPDF directly you can also set the base path that DomPDF loads from, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186282/3051959) for another answer about this.

Comment: tried that, it will not generate pdf for me. it will just only keeps on loading forever.

Comment: same when css is in html file. preview is ok but result pdf is not same as preview. it seems not working with some css attributes. for example, width % works but other doesn't work well

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having frustration with this, Sn0wCrack's answer was close, but for me, using the public facing URL worked best.

This didn't work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path('reports/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

This however did work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('reports/css/bootstrap.css')}}">
```

The ASSET_URL variable must be set in your .env for this to work correctly.

**Note: You can also use {{url('path')}} for this but it doesn't work when hosting on serverless like Vapor, if you use asset, it will rewrite the asset url by injecting the ASSET_URL for you on the deployment. You do not have to inject the ASSET_URL yourself when using Vapor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel and need to load external CSS links inside a Blade file, follow these steps:

First, load the external CSS in your Blade file.

Then, in your controller, use the following code to load HTML with an external CSS link:

```php
$html = View::make('your view full path')->render();
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
return $dompdf->stream('example.pdf');
```

In this code, replace `'your view full path'` with the actual path to your view. This will generate a PDF with the rendered HTML and stream it to the client.